# setup elastix extension as trunk

Tags: asterisk, sip, elastix

Good morning.
I have started working from home. My office has an elastix server and I have access to my extension from outside (ext: 126 ... BIG secret). i also have an elastix server at home, and so I do NOT want to setup this second configuration on every phone in the house. Is it possible to setup the extension the office pbx is offering me (126) as a TRUNK on my elastix, so I can just use an outbound route to access office extensions simply by prepending a "6" ..(i.e 6111 on HOME machine calls ext 111 on office machine)? I have setup the outbound route correctly (I think) as : () + 6 | [ZXX] (NO prepend, t as prefix and ZXX as match pattern), But I cant get the trunk to work. currently I have set it up as:

```
trunk name: office-126

username=126
secret=******
type=peer
qualify=yes
insecure=invite
host={office server external ip}
fromdomain={office server external ip}
disallow=all
allow=g729
context=from-trunk
fromuser=126

User context: 126

username=126
secret=****
type=friend
nat=yes
host={office server external ip}
fromdomain={office server external ip}
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=g729
dtmfmode=rfc2833
insecure=invite
```

Answer (score -2):

Sure it is posible. Most providers offer sip extensions, not trunk.

You have add registration string

```
register=>username:password@ip
```

For more info see manual about sip.conf

Comment: like this: [ext]:[pwd]@[ip]/[ext]

Comment: debug is offtopic here. Check sip show registry, check sip debug and settings on other pbx.